# There is some error in my SQL query for inserting image to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have an error in my SQL query for inserting image in database of MySQL.

When I try to save image error occur in SQL query for inserting image. The error is this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2( .?/279<<

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form action="http://localhost/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
      <input type="file" name="image" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("not conected");
  mysql_select_db("image") or die("not selected");

  $file_name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
  $myfile=file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
  $q="INSERT INTO imagee(image_id,image_name,image)
                  VALUES('','$file_name','$myfile')";
  mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: stop using **mysql_*** as they are deprecated, 2 don't store the image in the database, store it's name.. and move the file to a folder you want..

Comment: Same as @Naruto.
Question: is the table name really "imagee" (with double e)?

Comment: i dont know the code for moving a file to a folder can you tell me the code for moving file to folder

Comment: yes table name is imagee wth double ee

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the definition of your `imagee` table.

Comment: All you need to know about [uploading files in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) Oddly enough I found it in the PHP Manual. _The **last place** you would of expected it to be of course_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form action="phpfilename.php" method="post" 
       enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input  type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">

 

$file=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$dest="uploads/$file";
$src=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($src,$dest);

$result=mysql_query("insert into tablename(dbfieldname) values('$dest')");
```

Comment: thanx.it is vry help.image store in folder.can plz give me more help about storing image to database..

Comment: You need to store image name along with its location in database not an image.

so,

$dest will store the image name with location in your databse. i already given query above. try it and tell me if any difficulty.

Comment: Use this query for your table:

Here image_name is your table field , so the name stored in this field.

$q="INSERT INTO imagee(image_name)
                  VALUES('$dest')";

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $myfile;
```

to see how does that data looks.

You might want to

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
```

before using into INSERT query.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php