# Upload image and save form data into a Mysql db using php

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

I am writing a code where I can upload an image in a folder and save data form into a Mysql db. At the moment just Saving data form in a db table is working but I can't upload the image in a folder. This is the code:

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['upload_img'])){

$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];      
$file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp_name  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if($file_name){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"images/$file_name");

            }
}
?>
<?php
  include 'guestconfig/config.php';

if (isset($_POST['upload_img']) && $_POST['upload_img']=="invia")
{
        $image = $file_name;
        $title = addslashes($_POST['title']);
        $price = addslashes($_POST['price']);



  $sql = "INSERT INTO testone
(image,title,price) VALUES ('$image', '$title','$price')";
  if($result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()))
  {
    echo "Inserimento avvenuto con successo.<br>
    Vai alla <a href=\"index.php\">Home Amministrazione</a>";
  }
}else{
  ?>
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
  <td>
  <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="xxx" />
  <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="xxx" />
  </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>

  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>upload image </label><br>
<input type="file" name="image"><br>
<br><br>

title:
<input name="title" type="text"><br><br>

price:
<input name="price" type="text"><br><br>

<input name="upload_img" type="submit" value="invia">
</form>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
  <?php
}
?>
<br>
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks! :)

**EDIT:** Ok, now I can upload my image but I can't save the image name (before I could). How can I do it, please? Thanks! :)

**EDIT2:** Ok, now it's perfect... Thanks to everybody! :)

Comment: What is  `ctype="multipart/form-data"`??

Comment: use this image upload code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320872/there-is-some-error-in-my-sql-query-for-inserting-image-to-mysql-database/37321402#37321402

Comment: Use enctype="multipart/form-data" instead of ctype

Comment: use enctype="multipart/form-data" instead of ctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace `ctype="multipart/form-data"` with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
   if(!empty($file_name)){
                  if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"images/".$file_name))
echo "image uploaded";
else  echo "image not uploaded";


                }
```

Comment: Ok, I correct it :) but now why the image name is not saved in my db? Thanks again

Comment: @Marci why you have used addslashes function??

Answer (score 1):

form tag must be like this

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and in php you can do something like this

```
if(!empty($file_name)){
              move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"images/".$file_name);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have error in form tag**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```